# Error while making changes in a linked list using functions outside main():

Tags: c, struct

I tried to create a linked list with 4 nodes and then added a node using the `Insert()` fucntion. The overall program has the following framework.

1. `struct Node`: Defining the structure of each node of my linked list.
2. `Node_s* Initialize()`: This is just to initialize an empty node and return a pointer to the rest of the list; this is made just to satisfy the requirement of the program.
3. `int Insert()`: This function inserts a node such that the sorting of the list is maintained!
4. `main()`: I am executing the program here in main, by calling the functions `Initialize()` and `Insert()`

I think there is some problem in the way the insert() function is interacting with the main function. The changes I am making in the insert() function are not showing up in the main function. Can someone help me figure out why this is happening?

> Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 


typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* next;
} Node_s;


Node_s* Initialize(){

Node_s init_node;

Node_s* headlist;
init_node.data = 0;
headlist = init_node.next ;

return headlist;

}

int Insert(Node_s* listhead, int data){

Node_s* ptr = listhead;

if(data>0){
    while((data > ptr->data)&&(ptr->next!=NULL)){
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }

    Node_s a;
    a.data = data;

    if(ptr->next==NULL){
        a.next = NULL;
    }
    else{
        a.next = ptr->next;
    }

    ptr->next = &a;
    int count =0;

    Node_s* potr = listhead;

    printf("\ninside the function\n ");

    while( potr!= NULL)
    {
        printf("count %d %d \n" , count, potr->data);
        count = count +1;
        potr = potr->next;
    }

    return 0;
}
else{
    printf("enter valid positive integer");
    return 1;
}
}

int main() 

{

// 1st Node
Node_s two;
Node_s* ptr = Initialize(); 
ptr = &two;

// 2nd Node
two.data = 1;
Node_s three;
two.next = &three;

// 3rd Node
three.data = 2;
Node_s four;
three.next = &four;

// 4th Node
four.data = 3;
four.next = NULL ;

Insert(ptr, 5);

printf("\n outside the function\n");

int count =0;
Node_s* potr = ptr;
    while( potr!= NULL)
    {
        printf("count %d %d \n" , count, potr->data);
        count = count +1;
        potr = potr->next;
    }

return 0;
```

}

> Output message

```
inside the function
 count 0 1 
count 1 2 
count 2 3 
count 3 5 

 outside the function
count 0 1 
count 1 2 
count 2 3 
count 3 82624112 
count 4 84386816 
count 5 0 
count 6 -17958193 
zsh: segmentation fault  
"/Users/as/Desktop/A2/"tempCodeRunnerFile
```

Comment: To begin with `Initialize()` returns a pointer to a local variable that goes out of scope as soon as the function ends. There's probably more to uncover... You need to learn about dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @Fe2O3 Can I not do it without using dynamic memory allocation? I did not use malloc as I have not yet read in depth about it. I know that malloc will create a dynamic memory in heap and return a pointer to that memory address. And then we can typecast it to our choice of data type, like here we will typecast it to (struct Node*) ; and the code will be something like `struct Node* node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));`

Comment: `Node_s *node = malloc( sizeof *node );` does the same thing (more reliably) with much less typing (and reading). Keep learning.

Answer (score 0):

In the comments under the OP, the question has been raised, "Can I make a linked list" without using `malloc()`.

Here is a few lines of code that does that. Consider the limits of this approach. Perhaps you can slowly play-with and adapt some of this to increase your understanding of linked lists and memory usage.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
} Node_s;

int main() {
    Node_s nd5 = { 99, NULL };
    Node_s nd4 = { 50, &nd5 };
    Node_s nd3 = { 40, &nd4 };
    Node_s nd2 = { 30, &nd3 };
    Node_s nd1 = { 20, &nd2 };
    Node_s nd0 = { 10, &nd1 };

    int cnt = 0;
    for( Node_s *p = &nd0; p; p = p->next ) {
        printf( "count %d %d\n", cnt, p->data );
        cnt += 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
count 0 10
count 1 20
count 2 30
count 3 40
count 4 50
count 5 99
```

Comment: Okay, that looks nice! Can you also elaborate a bit about what I am doing wrong in terms of memory usage?

Comment: @Formal_that Yes, it **looks nice**. It is easy to read, and has minimal code. The variables all have justifiable names, and the indentation follows standard practices. These are the basics that are not found in your code. As such, people who might be able to help you solve a problem glance at the question and move on to something that shows clarity and effort. You can't build on shaky foundations. Apply the basics (and learn what "local variables" are) and you will make progress and receive help when needed. It's up to you...